# Google Cloud app engine with Laravel: unix_socket issue

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, unix-socket

I am using Laravel version 5.1.*. Here is my db config file...

```
  'mysql' => [
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => 'localhost',
                'database'  => 'database',
                'username'  => 'username',
                'password'  => 'password',
                'unix_socket'  => '/cloudsql/zoho-portal-159018:us-central1:zoho-portal',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
                'strict'    => false,
            ],
```

it gives error No such file or directory. It seems, unix_socket is the issue. But exact same config works when I use normal PDO connect without laravel....

```
$DBH_SOCKET = '/cloudsql/zoho-portal-159018:us-central1:zoho-portal';
        $DBH_NAME = 'DBH_NAME';

        $cns="mysql:unix_socket=".$DBH_SOCKET.";dbname=".$DBH_NAME.";charset=utf8";
        $user='user';
        $password='password';
        try{
            $DBH = new PDO($cns,$user,$password);
            $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
```

If It works in normal single php file without laravel... then it must should work in laravel way. But not not working.. Any comments highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You still need to set the right database name, username and password in your `.env.php` or `config/database.php`

Comment: yes I did... still same issue... thanks :)

Comment: @salimbutex did you solve this problem ? If so can you post your answer